# Options to Debug Flutter Apps from Ubuntu/Windows to Mac Mini

Tags: ios, windows, ubuntu, debugging, flutter

We have a Mac Mini and two systems Ubuntu and Windows. We want to develop in-between these systems to debug the iOS version of the Flutter App on the Mac Mini.

What options are there to seamlessly switch from Ubuntu/Windows to iOS debugging?

Comment: How about android studio on each of them and github for storing the files and updating ? There would need to be some extra bits like xcode for the Iphone, but I think it should be ok ?

Comment: Remote debugging might not work yet. Check the Github issues in flutter/flutter and flutter/flutter-intellij